# Argument is undefined in Firefox using angular js and typeahead, but it works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, typeahead.js

I have a ng-model set in an (angular) Typeahead. The ng-model should pass an argument into the function linkToEvent() It passes in a number in Chrome and Safari but it doesnt in FireFox. In FF the argument is undefined. 
Could someone help me with a proper solution?

Using angular JS and Siyfion/angular-typeahead.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="eventToLink" class="typeahead" sf-typeahead type="text" datasets="eventsDataset" placeholder="zoek hier het evenement">
          <button ng-click="linkToEvent(ticket.id, eventToLink.id)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs button-add-event" data-dismiss="alert">voeg toe
          </button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

It passes ticket.id and eventToLink.id. For ticket.id I get a number but for eventToLink.id I get a undefined in FireFox. ticket.id is somewhere else defined in the HTML in a ng-repeat directive.

Controller JS

```
$scope.linkToEvent = function(ticketId, eventId){
    console.log(ticketId);
    // eventId gives a undefined in FireFox
    console.log(eventId);
    $http({
        url: '/ajax/ticket/linkToEvent',
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'ticketId': ticketId,
            'eventId': eventId
        }),
        header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(data, status){
        $scope.events = data.events;
        $scope.something = data.something;
        if (status == 200){
            $scope.alerts = [];
            $scope.alerts.push({type: 'danger', msg: 'OK'});
            $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
                $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
            };
        }
  })
```